# Prove there is one solution in real numbers: exponential function $\ f(x)=3^x+4^x-5^x $

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I have a function

$$\ f(x)=3^x+4^x-5^x $$

How to prove taht f(x) has only one solution in real numbers? I have tried to take a derivative through $\ e^{x\ln3} $ substitution:

$$\ f(x)' = \ln(3)3^x+ \ln(4)4^x- \ln(5)5^x $$

However, I am stuck at the moment and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Do you want to prove that  the equation $f(x)=0$ has only one solution $x=2$? For this problem, you can consider $g(x)=(\frac{3}{5})^x+(\frac{4}{5})^x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to finding the solutions of

$$\left(\frac35\right)^x+\left(\frac45\right)^x=1.$$

But the derivative of the LHS is

$$\log\frac35\left(\frac35\right)^x+\log\frac45\left(\frac45\right)^x<0$$ and the function is strictly decreasing.

As $x=2$ is a solution, it is the only one.

---

For a very rough solution, notice that $0.6\approx 0.8^2$ and with $t:=0.8^x$,

$$t^2+t=1\implies t=\phi-1=0.618\cdots$$ and $$x\approx\log_{0.8}(\phi-1){}\approx 2.15\cdots$$

This can be used as a starting value for Newton's iterations.

Comment: How do you find x?

Comment: By inspection, recognizing that $3,4,5$ is a Pythagorean triple. Otherwise a numerical method is needed.

Comment: Probably I am interested in numerical method. I think it's more universal.

Comment: @Question: as far as I know, no numerical method is able to tell you the exact *number* of roots of a transcendental equation like this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider $\frac{f(x)}{4^x}$.